# Multiplicar duas colunas em um select Com GroupBy

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select, group-by, count

Como Consigo Fazer essa multiplicação? a tabela se encontra assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Oque tem que ser feito é agrupar as disciplinas 11 e 13, contar quantos 'sit' F e Null tem e multiplicar pela 'qntd_aula'... Eu consegui chegar até esse select...

```
select d.id, d.nome, (count(sit) * f.qntd_aula)F, ((count(sit is null) - count(sit))* f.qntd_aula) P, qntd_aula from frequencia_aluno_dia2020 f, disciplina d where idpessoa = 62644 and    d.id = f.iddisciplina group by d.id,qntd_aula;
```

mas não fica agrupado corretamente olhem..
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu poderia resolver? Deixando com que Lingua Portuguesa esteja com F = 2 e P = 5.

Answer (score -2):

Man com a clausula WITH você consegue criar uma expressão comum em tempo de execução, é como se você criasse uma view na hora de executar sua query, o que faz com que ela fique muito mais rapida que uma view real.
Por exemplo no seu caso você poderia criar um with, relecionando todos os dados da sua table e criando uma nova coluna chamada `sit_real` transformando todos os nulos em F.
Dessa forma:

```
WITH vw_dados (id, data, idescola, idturma, idmatricula, ra, idpessoa, sit, sit_real, sit_mat, iddisciplina, bio, email, app, sms, push, qntd_sala) AS
(
  SELECT id, data, idescola, idturma, idmatricula, ra, idpessoa, sit,
case when sit is null then 'F' else sit end as sit_real
, sit_mat, iddisciplina, bio, email, app, sms, push, qntd_sala
)
SELECT ...
```